# Deployed angular app to Azure web app service - But not showing the .webp images

Tags: angular, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, webp

I have an Angular application with routing that is hosted on an Azure App Service and has an Azure Devops Pipeline. The website displays perfectly but the webP images return with a 404 status code. I have my `web.config` set to include WebP images with:

```xml
<mimeMap fileExtension="webp" mimeType="image/webp"/>
```

I expected this to fix my issue, but they do not display at all. When I go to the link directly, I get a page with an error message:

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

I have never asked questions on this website so this is very new to me.

Comment: Do you have the `mimeMap` element under `configuration` - `system.webServer` - `staticContent`? Is there a CDN active for the App Service? Can you verify the image is actually there? Also: is there a reason you're not using a [Static Web App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/overview)? Might fit your scenario perfectly.

Comment: I do have the `mimeMap` in the correct position and I have tried making the `fileExtention` to `.webp` instead as well. I have verified the images are there and present using Kudu if that is what you are asking. The reason I'm not using Static Web Apps is because this project was implemented this way before I could make that call.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the web.config as an asset in your angular.json file.

```
    "assets": [
             "src/favicon.ico",
             "src/assets",
             "src/web.config"
           ],
```

2. move the web.config file into the src file of your solution.

this is how it ended up working for me.